# Utilizar o Intent.ACTION_SEND compartilhar texto no facebook

Tags: android

Estou utilizando o código abaixo para compartilhar texto com o facebook. O problemas é que nas outras redes funcionam, mas no facebook fica em branco.
Alguém já passou por isso?

```
Intent compartilha = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
compartilha.setType("text/plain");
compartilha.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Compartilhando frase");
compartilha.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Texto exemplo!");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartilha, "Compartilhando"));
```

Comment: Me parece que você achou um bug do facebook que não foi e nem vai ser corrigido... Esse problema é proposital para te forçar a usar o SDK do Facebook para Android. Só dessa forma é possível compartilhar de forma correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso realmente acontece e é como foi projetado, de acordo com o Facebook. [Dê uma olhada nesse bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/332619626816423/):

> Jesse Chen ·  · Facebook Team
>
> Hi Facebook Developers,
>
> This issue is going to be closed by design because our API does not
> support pre-filling the message for users as seen in our Policy
> Documentation here
> (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/application_integration_points/)
> under Platform Policy IV.2.
>
> Thanks, Jesse

Em outras palavras, se você tenta enviar alguma `Intent` para o Facebook com um texto, eles não sabem se o usuário escreveu isso ou foi uma outra aplicação. Ele simplesmente ignora o texto e deixa que o usuário realmente escreva o que ele deseja.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta.